# Проблемы с parallax

Tags: html, css, parallax

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 53px;
  background: #fefefe;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.hero {
  background: #00f;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

.product {
  background: #003;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #030;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <div class="parallax">
    <div class="hero">
      <img src="img/flowers.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Привет.Проблема такая навигационный бар который с фисированной позицией стоит поверх скрола.Если же его тоже поместить в группу с параллаксом он становится не фиксированный.Хотелось бы что бы навбар был фисорованный и скрол был не под навбаром.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  
  padding-top: 53px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 53px;
  background: #fefefe;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.hero {
  background: #00f;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

.product {
  background: #003;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #030;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <div class="parallax">
    <div class="hero">
      <img src="img/flowers.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте контейнер *parallax-wrapper* и задайте в нем отступ на величину header-а

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 53px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.parallax-wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 53px
 }

.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.hero {
  background: #00f;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

.product {
  background: #003;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #030;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <div class="parallax-wrapper">
    <div class="parallax">
      <div class="hero">
        <img src="img/flowers.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="product"></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: И получится так что скрол не доходит до навбара.Я этого могу добиться когда выношу с контейнера parallax nav.Мне же нужно что бы скрол охвативал и хедер

Comment: тогда не стоит использовать *position: fixed*

Comment: Есть какая-то альтернатива?